# Zip Element in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a problem with the following function in Haskell that zip only elements "B" in a list:

```
data El = A | B deriving (Show)

zS :: [El] -> [El]
zS [] = []
zS (A:xs) = A : zS xs
zS (B:xs) = B : zS xs
zS (B:B:xs) = B : zS xs
zS (B:A:xs) = B : A : zS xs
```

When I test the function `zS` the result should be:

```
zS [B, B, A, A, B, B, B, A, B ] --> [B, A, A, B, A, B ]
```

but it does not work. Also, when I compile the code, Haskell return a Warning like this:

```
 Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for 'zS':
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if the order of your functions is relevant here. (B:xs) is a superset of (B:B:xs). So maybe if you move the more specialized cases up it might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

When you define a function with multiple patterns, the patterns which are too specific should be defined at the beginning and the broader patterns should be defined at the end.

**Explanation**

In your case,

```
zS (B:xs) = B : zS xs
```

already matches any list which starts with `B`. So,

```
zS (B:B:xs) = B : zS xs
zS (B:A:xs) = B : A : zS xs
```

will already be matched by `zS (B:xs) = B : zS xs` itself. That is why Haskell is calling it out by saying

```
Pattern match(es) are overlapped
```

To fix this, define the specific patterns at the beginning, like this

```
zS :: [El] -> [El]
zS [] = []
zS (B:B:xs) = B : zS xs
zS (B:A:xs) = B : A : zS xs
zS (A:xs) = A : zS xs
zS (B:xs) = B : zS xs
```

---

**Note:** Your code has a bug,

```
zS (B:B:xs) = B : zS xs
```

Here, you are including `B`, if you find two matches and no matter how many times `B` is repeated. Instead, you can recurse like this

```
zS (B:B:xs) = zS (B:xs)
```

so that

```
zS (B:A:xs) = B : A : zS xs
```

will take care of repeating `B`s for you.

Comment: @user2225104 [TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read) is for the people who want to know the crisp solution instead of reading a long text.